# Как выводить значение типа point

Tags: mysql, laravel

Как выводить нормально значение координат? хранятся в бд с типом point

```
#attributes: array:5 [▼
    "id" => 1
    "coordinates" => b"\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x01\x00\x00\x00 ¼þ­
     Ý›G@\x00\x00\x00\x00ýßC@"
    "name" => "Площадка№1"
    "cost" => null
    "description" => "тест"
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Comment: По дефолту, Laravel не предоставляет свое решение данной проблемы. Но есть костыль https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22360969/laravel-model-with-point-polygon-etc-using-dbraw-expressions Не стал оформлять в отдельный ответ, т.к. там и без знания языка все понятно